# Gridview property in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

i have a doubt in grid view. In Data list we have a property call RepeatDirection (horizontal or vertical). is there any property  in  gridview control displaying the data in horizontal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Gridview can show multiple records per row. Nesting Controls could be an option.
eg: Another Gridview/DataList in itemTemplate. but this need the change existing DataFetching mechanism.

Comment: ok Shoaid Shaikh. so there is no option do display the multiple records in a single row

Comment: Yups. Its not supported by rendering logic of Gridview. Why don't you use DataList it can work easily this way..

Answer (score 0):

In Grid we have no option like that because datalist can stored each record at a time where as grid can bind datatable at a time i mean datatable or dataset. further information please give more information on gridview what u want exactly